# SQL-How to sample my dataset based on condition - (TeraData db)

Tags: sql, random, bigdata, teradata, sample

I have a dataset of 1.5M customers.
I grouped the customers based on some field to 12 different groups and these is the distribution:

[image]

My mission is to take a sample of 200K customers only, but it must have the same distribution shown here (based on the grouping percentage).
Any suggestions? I'm using SQL in Teradata db.

**I looked online for some solutions but with no success. The SAMPLE() function didn't bring me the solution I needed (or maybe I didn't used it right)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the distribution is in a table:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by grp order by random()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by grp) as grp
      from customers c
     ) c
     distribution d
where seqnum <= c.grp * d.percent * 200000;
```

This enumerates the values for each group.  And then takes the appropriate number of rows.  Note:  If a group is not large enough, then the number of rows returned will be less than 200k.

I don't have Teradata on hand and I'm not 100% sure that `random()` is allowed in the `row_number()` call.  If not, some other similar function can be used to randomize the results for each group.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something quick and dirty, I think you can do it using stratified sampling:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
SAMPLE 
  WHEN group = 0 THEN (.40 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 1 THEN (.17 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 2 THEN (.11 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 3 THEN (.04 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 4 THEN (.06 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 5 THEN (.01 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 6 THEN (.05 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 7 THEN (.05 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 8 THEN (.02 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 9 THEN (.03 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 10 THEN (.04 * 200000)
  WHEN group = 11 THEN (.02 * 200000)
END
```

Keep in mind, if there aren't sufficient rows in a group to meet the requested sample size, you will end up with fewer rows than expected, unless you specify the `WITH REPLACEMENT` clause.  And if you want a "true" sample, you need to specify the `RANDOMIZED ALLOCATION` clause.

[TD Manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/2_MC9vCtAJRlKle2Rpb0mA/XTSw8n_%7ExbTDRIHwHyUiWA)